# Loop data in ArrayList

Tags: java, list, arraylist, singleton

I am currently building a practice app in Android Studio, which is actually a native shopping app. I'm stuck and in need of a solution. How can I insert data that I have looped from my arrayList into textViews?

The following code is a snap of my shopping cart activity-class:

```
// component declaration
private TextView[] nameText, manufactureText, priceText;
private EditText[] quantityText;

// --> in onCreate
for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {

    nameText[i] = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    manufactureText[i] = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    priceText[i] = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    // imageView[i].setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);

    quantityText[i] = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
    quantityText[i].setInputType( InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER );

    for (Item item : ShoppingCartController.getInstance().myProducts) {
        nameText[i].setText( "Name: " + item.getName() );
        manufactureText[i].setText( "Manufacture: " + item.getManufacture() );
        priceText[i].setText("Price: R " + item.getPrice() );
        quantityText[i].setInputType( InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER );
        quantityText[i].setText( item.getQuantity().toString() );
        //item.getImage();

        Log.d(TAG, "Viewing Shopping Cart\n"
                + item.getName() + "\n"
                + item.getManufacture() + "\n"
                + item.getImage() + "\n"
                + item.getPrice() + "\n"
        );


    }
    productLayout.addView(nameText[i]);
    productLayout.addView(manufactureText[i]);
    productLayout.addView(priceText[i]);
    productLayout.addView(quantityText[i]);
    // productLayout.addView(imageView[i]);

}
```

productLayout code snap:

```
productLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
productLayout.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
productLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
productLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

And in my Singleton class I have an arrayList I have been using:

```
 public ArrayList<Item> myProducts = new ArrayList<>();
```

The Item Class has the following instance variable:

```
private String name;
private String manufacture;
private String price;
private String image;
private Integer quantity;
```

Comment: It is vague what you are asking. You are iterating over your products in `for` loop: `for (Item item : ShoppingCartController.getInstance().myProducts)`. So is there any problem on that?

Comment: Maybe you want `Item item
 = ShoppingCartController.getInstance().myProducts.get(i);` instead of `for (Item item : ShoppingCartController.getInstance().myProducts){...}`?

Comment: I want to be able to output what I have looped into textView...

Comment: where is your textView class?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, but I created textView programmatically and made them to be array so that I can loop them while displaying data

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you're asking for. You haven't shown any log statements with your problem.

However your arrays at the very beginning are not initialized, something like this:

```
nameText = new TextView[arraySize]
```

Other than that you must be very specific with your question if you want to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The items of **TextViews** are not initialized. You have to initialize them before assigning any value. So initialize them before the for loop.

```
  nameText = new TextView[arraysize];
  manufactureText=new TextView[arraysize];
  priceText = new TextView[arraysize];
```

then you can assign values to them.

```
nameText[i] = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
```

the above line do nothing without initializing. You have to initialize it first
like `nameText = new TextView[arraysize];` then you can perform

```
 nameText[i] = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
```

hope it helps.

Comment: I can iterate through my products, the problem is displaying them in texView, it loops but --> it only shows my last index data in the array